# html in flexiframe call its parent flexApp method

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, apache-flex, iframe, flex4

I have a flex application with iframe .there is a HTML in this iframe, how can i call the method of flex in the html's js?
     xmlns:mapFrame="http://code.google.com/p/flex-iframe/"

```
 public function test(str:String):void{
     trace('params from js'+str);
      }

 <mapFrame:IFrame id="frm" source="mapHtml/overlay.html" height="90%" width="100%"     />
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/flex-users/flex-iframe/tree/master/examples/CallIFrameFunction

say your iframe have id named `iFrameWithJSfunctions` then we can call it like `iFrameWithJSfunctions.callIFrameFunction('showAlert');` source of the iframe have javascript  and we can call js's function name `showAlert`

may this will help you!!

Comment: Communication between Flex and javascript

I.e. calling back into the Flex app from the page and calling into javascript from the Flex app. The way I implemented this was using FABridge. See the IFrameBridgeTest demo. So it's possible but it's not simple.